# Loading @font-face in JavaFX yields loadStylesheetUnPrivileged

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I am getting this error when running code with the stylesheet below:

```
Jan 21, 2016 11:20:40 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/home/luiserebii/workspace/WingDingsConverter/bin/fonts/8bit.tff]
```

The directories seem correct. I'm using Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04, if that makes a difference.

```
@font-face {

    src: url('../fonts/8bit.tff');

}
```

UPDATED ERROR IN WINDOWS:

```
Jan 23, 2016 1:10:00 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/L:/Luiserebii's%20Data/Computer%20Science/Java/workspace/PowerballFX/bin/fonts/8bit.ttf]
Jan 23, 2016 1:10:00 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/L:/Luiserebii's%20Data/Computer%20Science/Java/workspace/PowerballFX/bin/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf]
```

I suspect it has to do with the way the slashes are oriented?

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `.tff`? Usually TrueType fonts have `ttf` extension (two T's, one F)

Comment: I... don't know how I missed that three times in a row, on three separate programs lol. Perhaps I should get a vision test? Thanks haha

Comment: Alright, I must be crazy. Now running this code from Windows to try and export to .exe, and it's giving me similar errors again. It can't be the file extension, but I suspect it's the slashes?